# is there a way to create graphs for IO on server

Tags: io

is there a tool which allows to save a simple data to a file regarding the IO usage, so that I could use them to display a graph of IO usage?

I need to use it on my server, with no graphical environment so any X application is of no use here. I just need to collect something like

time:(disk read/write)

so that I could make a graph from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dstat` like this:

```
dstat --time --disk --output disk-stats.csv 60
```

this will write disk activity into the disk-stats.csv file every 60 seconds